# PrintOut method prints random pages

Tags: vba, printing, excel, excel-2007

I have a printout button in Excel which is assigned to the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets(Array("Cover", "1", "1-1", "2", "3", "4")).PrintOut , , 1
    Sheet1.PrintOut , , 1 'use this method to print all together at the end instead printing individually.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However, instead of printing the sheets it starts off printing 100 random pages with 3-10 values per page (it does not really make sense). Print ranges are set and checked across all sheets, I do not really understand where the error comes from.

Any ideas?

Thanks upfront!

Comment: When I hit the button firstly a popup opens which includes the X Pages I want to print (and it prints them correctly) and after that "Print Y of X.." popup closed an other popup opens stating "Print 1 of 196" and the random pages turn out. I have no idea where from that code the second print command comes from...

Comment: You're calling PrintOut twice - why?

Comment: `"Print 1 of 196"` Something is not right with the Print Ranges. You might want to check it again. Use this for every sheet and see what address do you get? `Debug.Print UsedRange.Address`

Comment: Have you tried using `PrintPreview` to see if you can piece together where the random values are coming from? Save paper!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use PrintOut in that way:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'If you want only to print the active sheet
    Sheet1.PrintOut

    'Printing a range, from the first page until page 23, one copy:
    Sheet1.PrintOut 1,23,1

    'Printing only a single page (23), two copies:
    Sheet1.PrintOut 23,23,2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Look a:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253.aspx